# Finding a regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String in java that is actually a JSON object. Inside the string I am trying to find a pattern matching this

> "uris" : ["www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com"]

I need help in creating a pattern string to find a match for this. I have no idea of automata theory and regular expressions.

Note: the above substring will always start at "uris" and end at "]" but there can be any number of spaces in between.

Comment: what's wrong with calling `YourJsonObject.getJSONArray("uris");` and traverse the array using loop etc

Comment: the content should be always a url like your do, or it can be any thing?

Comment: Why not use proper JSON parser? You would avoid many potential problems like handling keys which only ends with `uris`, or searching within values of other keys like `key="foo uris: [something]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following *regex* :

```
"uris".*?\]
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/y7TO0H/1)**

**Java** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/gTgWzr) )

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class RegEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "\"uris\" : [\"www.google.com\", \"www.yahoo.com\"]";
        String r = "\"uris\".*?\\]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group()); //"uris" : ["www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com"]
        }
    }
}
```